# Accessing value(s) of ActionController Parameters hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters, actioncontroller

I'm having trouble with parameters in an app upgraded from 4.2 to 5.1. I have permitted my parameters, but as the documentation states, I'm getting back an object for my hash array, but can't seem to access the values of it. How can I just get the value of this object?

```
    {"_method"=>"delete",   "authenticity_token"=>"Z6ZqriiuXu6ODDqhGgocGiaN12rjKD6pUB6n/2v+CABZDAjwLzwczsMM3nM8f0PI0nww43o5mlC35HK+9PVa8w==",
    "domain_name"=>"test.testmodule2.com.",
    "hosted_zone_id"=>"/hostedzone/XXXXXXXXXX",
    "ttl"=>"3600",
    "type"=>"A",
    "value"=>[{"value"=>"1.1.1.1"}],
    "id"=>"/hostedzone/XXXXXXXXXX"}
```

```
def record_params
    params.permit!([:hosted_zone_id, :domain_name, :type, :ttl, :alias, :value]).to_h!
end


def destroy
    value = params[:value]
    # returns [<ActionController::Parameters {"value"=>"1.1.1.1"} permitted: true>]
    # would like it to return [{"value"=>"1.1.1.1"}]
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that hash is the value of `params[:value]`, then access the `value` key inside, like:

```
params[:value] = {
  "_method"=>"delete",   
  "authenticity_token"=>"...",
  "domain_name"=>"test.testmodule2.com.",
  "hosted_zone_id"=>"/hostedzone/XXXXXXXXXX",
  "ttl"=>"3600",
  "type"=>"A",
  "value"=>[{"value"=>"1.1.1.1"}],
  "id"=>"/hostedzone/XXXXXXXXXX"
}

params['value']['value'][0]['value']
# => "1.1.1.1"
params['value']['value'][0].keys
# => ["value"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. When I puts [:value], it prints out the correct value, but when I call that variable later on when I need to to be just the array object, it returns `"[<ActionController::Parameters {"value"=>"1.1.1.1"} permitted: true>]"`. Any thoughts?

Comment: Due to your structure you'll have to access the array containt the ActionControllerParameters and then the value key like `p params['value']['value'][0]['value']`

Comment: So there isn't a way now to just get the array/hash rather than the value?

Comment: Try with `params.to_unsafe_h[:value]`, do you get your expected output?

Comment: That last one did it! I was able to pass through the hash rather than the object.

Thank you so much for your help- I really appreciate it!

Comment: Glad to help you. You can also take a look [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html) to get a better idea on how it works.